# Why does the differential of a minimal model (of an algebra, operad) need be decomposable?

Tags: homological-algebra, operads

In operad theory, a minimal model of a dg-operad $\mathcal{P}$ (or dga A) is given by a quasi-free resolution $(\mathcal{T}(E),\partial) \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} P$ where $f$ is a quasi-isomorphism and the differential $\partial$ is decomposable, that is, $\partial(e) \in \mathcal{T}(E)^{(\geq 2)}$ for generators $e$, which means the trees appearing in $\partial(e)$ have at least two vertexes.

I am wondering what the significance is of the decomposability of the differential? What are its implications? Which advantages does it provide that a cofibrant resolution does not?

The main implication that I expect, is that it is used to prove unicity of the minimal model (see *operads in Algebra, Topology and Physics*). However, this proof also requires the operads involved to have no $0$-ary operation and only the identity as $1$-ary operation. This uniqueness also does not extend to props (see *a resolution (minimal model) of the prop for bialgebras* by Markl), yet the decomposability is also imposed for its minimal model.

I would be very interested in seeing where this condition plays a role. Especially with respect to operadic cohomology of $\mathcal{P}$-algebras and modules.

Comment: Decomposability is easy to explain: if there exists generators $v$ and $w$ related by $dw=v$ then, informally, $v$ can be dropped because it is a boundary and $w$ can be dropped because it is not a cycle. Essentially, it guarantees there are no redundant generators in your model.

Comment: So it is a requisite for being as small as possible, but it is not always sufficient to show there is a unique smallest model?